# VC.net String to LPWSTR

Tags: visual-c++

How can I transform from string to LPWSTR

```
String^ str= "hello world";
LPWSTR apppath= (LPWSTR)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(str).ToPointer());
```

But it doesn't work.After transformed:
[image]

Comment: You can't cast an 8-bit string to a wide string, that requires a conversion.  There's no point to it, just use Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni().  Do not forget to release again.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read single-byte characters (that's what `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi` is returning) as wide characters (that's what an `LPWSTR` type points to), and you're getting whatever is in memory interpreted as a wide-character string.

You need to marshal the appropriate type, and you need to be aware of the lifetime of the result. Here's an example program that shows one way to do it, modified from the MSDN example in [marshal_context::marshal_as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384856.aspx):

```
// compile with: /clr
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <msclr\marshal.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace msclr::interop;

int main() {
    marshal_context^ context = gcnew marshal_context();
    String^ str = "hello world";
    LPWSTR apppath = const_cast<wchar_t*>(context->marshal_as<const wchar_t*>(str));
    wprintf(L"%s\n", apppath);
    delete context;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that a reference to `apppath` is likely to be bogus after the deletion of `context`.