# vb.net convert string to LPWStr

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to invoke [CreateProcessWithTokenW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682434(v=vs.85).aspx) and I've got it mostly working, except I can't manage to pass the lpCommandLine value.  It is in a format called LPWSTR.  I have tried using a string variable, and a string builder variable (as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings#cpcondefaultmarshalingforstringsanchor5)) but neither worked.

Any support would be very much appreciated.

(PS: I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040707/vc-net-string-to-lpwstr) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659751/pcwstr-vs-lpwstr), and they didn't help - I'm looking for a vb.net solution if I can find one - ).

**Edited to include code:**

Here is the code in the program that calls the CreateProcessWithTokenW:

```
Private Sub LowerPriviledgeStart(ByVal ProgramName As String, ByVal CommandLine As String, ByVal WorkingDirectory As String)

    Try

        Dim currentProcess As Process = Process.GetCurrentProcess

        'Enable SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege in this process.  (This requires administrative privileges.)
        Dim hProcessToken As IntPtr = Nothing
        OpenProcessToken(currentProcess.Handle, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, hProcessToken)
        Dim tkp As TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
        tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1
        LookupPrivilegeValue(Nothing, SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME, tkp.TheLuid)
        tkp.Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED

        AdjustTokenPrivileges(hProcessToken, False, tkp, 0, Nothing, Nothing)

        'Get window handle representing the desktop shell.  This might not work if there is no shell window, or when
        'using a custom shell.  Also note that we're assuming that the shell is not running elevated.
        Dim hShellWnd As IntPtr = GetShellWindow()

        'Get the ID of the desktop shell process.
        Dim dwShellPID As IntPtr
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hShellWnd, dwShellPID)

        'Open the desktop shell process in order to get the process token.
        Dim hShellProcess As IntPtr = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, dwShellPID)
        Dim hShellProcessToken As IntPtr = Nothing
        Dim hPrimaryToken As IntPtr = Nothing

        'Get the process token of the desktop shell.
        OpenProcessToken(hShellProcess, TOKEN_DUPLICATE, hShellProcessToken)

        'Duplicate the shell's process token to get a primary token.
        Dim dwTokenRights As Integer = TOKEN_QUERY Or TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY Or TOKEN_DUPLICATE Or TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT Or TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID
        DuplicateTokenEx(hShellProcessToken, dwTokenRights, Nothing, SecurityImpersonation, TokenPrimary, hPrimaryToken)

        Dim si As STARTUPINFO = Nothing

        Dim pi As PROCESS_INFORMATION = Nothing

        si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si)

        Dim ptrWorkingDirectory As IntPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(WorkingDirectory)

        Dim sbCommandLine As New StringBuilder(256)
        sbCommandLine.Append(CommandLine)

        CreateProcessWithTokenW(hPrimaryToken, 0, ProgramName, sbCommandLine, 0, Nothing, ptrWorkingDirectory, si, pi)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub





<DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
Public Shared Function CreateProcessWithTokenW(hToken As IntPtr,
                                               dwLogonFlags As Integer,
                                               lpApplicationName As String,
                                               lpCommandLine As StringBuilder,
                                               dwCreationFlags As Integer,
                                               lpEnvironment As IntPtr,
                                               lpCurrentDirectory As IntPtr,
                                               ByRef lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO,
                                               ByRef lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Boolean
End Function
```

The above code needs to be run in a process with elevated privileges.

Using the above, the program to be launched does indeed get launched. However, it appears the Commandline value is not being passed.

In the program that is launched, I am using the following line of code to get the command line

```
 Dim CommandLine As String = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Command
```

which works fine normally.  I have also tried

```
  Dim CommandLine As String = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Command()
```

Comment: It's hard to tell you what you did wrong with *no* indication of what you *did*. Please post a [mcve] and the errors.

Comment: The correct type is `StringBuilder`, but you must also specify `CharSet.Unicode` in the `DllImport` attribute. As already mentioned please post an MCVE so that we can see what you're doing. It's not necessarily the P/Invoke declaration that's the problem.

Comment: Side note: You can use this answer of mine for P/Invoke reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46547553/3740093 -- It has been corrected and verified by [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088), who has great knowledge in P/Invoking.

Comment: Have you checked the return value of the function, and also `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`?

Comment: Also, I don't know whether this will make a difference, but here's the correct function declaration: `Public Shared Function CreateProcessWithTokenW(hToken As IntPtr, dwLogonFlags As UInteger, lpApplicationName As String, lpCommandLine As StringBuilder, dwCreationFlags As UInteger, lpEnvironment As IntPtr, lpCurrentDirectory As String, ByRef lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, ByRef lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean` -- Mainly I've changed the `DWORD` parameters to `UInteger`, and `lpCurrentDirectory` to a `String` rather than `IntPtr`.

Comment: I updated the function declaration as you recommended, the function when called returns a boolean true, and Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() returns a 0 (zero).   Same results, the application gets launched, but  Microsoft.VisualBasic.Command returns string.empty

Comment: Have you tried `Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ConsoleApplicationBase()`? It has a property .CommandLineArg (string collection).

Comment: My.Application.CommandLineArgs is not available.  My program is a wpf application.  Docs say it is available to Windows Applications, Console Applications, and Windows Services.  I guess WPF applications aren't considered (Form) Windows Applications.

Comment: yahoo!! the following worked!! thanks for all your help  ....                        
   Dim CommandLine() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs